# INSERT values from a JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This must be a duplicate, but I'm having trouble Googling the answer. I have the following Postgres tables:

```
stores:
   id - integer
   zipcode - varchar
   county - varchar, nullable
zipcode_to_county:
   zipcode - varchar
   county - varchar
```

Currently all the values of `county` in `stores` are null - I just know their zipcodes. Now I want to update the `county` column, by looking up the `zipcode` of each store in `zipcode_to_county`.

I can script this with Python, but can I do it directly in SQL?

Something like this perhaps:

```
INSERT into stores(county) (
  SELECT z.county FROM stores s 
  LEFT JOIN zipcode_to_county z
  WHERE s.zipcode=z.zipcode
);
```

I guess the inner query will return a set of rows, which then get inserted one-by-one, but I don't know how to make sure they're the "right" set of rows.

Not every zipcode will appear in the `zipcode_to_county` table, hence the need for a `LEFT JOIN` somewhere.

Comment: `left join ... on ..` not `where`

Comment: Why insert *  Now I want to update the county column*  Think you are looking for update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `UPDATE` the existing rows.

```
UPDATE stores
SET country = z.country
FROM zipcode_to_county z
WHERE stores.zipcode = z.zipcode;
```

No need for an outer join here, as that will only produce extra NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the `stores` table. There are several ways one of them is the following:

```
UPDATE stores
SET county = (SELECT county 
              FROM zipcode_to_county 
              WHERE zipcode_to_county.zipcode = stores.zipcode)
```